# swift - sort an array of objects by their optional boolean property without force unwrapping

Tags: ios, swift

I can sort this array of store objects by their 'flagship' boolean property, but how can I safely unwrap the 'flagship' property first?

```
let flagshipStores = self.stores.sort {
    $0.flagship! && !$1.flagship!
}
```

Comment: I'd think about whether you really need a "third state" (an optional Bool) of a **binary** type in your design?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not my design. I'm parsing a JSON object where flagship may be true, false, or not provided.

Comment: Can you treat *not provided* as false?

Comment: I agree with @vadian but you can use the nil coalescing operator to provide a default value of `false` but really that is something you should do when you unpack the JSON

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
let flagshipStores = self.stores.sort {
    guard let flagship0 = $0.flagship, let flagship1 = $1.flagship else { return false }
    return flagship0 && !flagship1
}
```

Comment: there's a bug here.  if only one is nil, this code returns 'false', but it should return ($0.flagship == nil && $1.flagship != nil) (if you want nil to sort before non-nil).

Answer (score 11):

One more approach: turn the `Bool?` into an `Int`, then compare the `Int`s. You get to specify how a `nil` value compares to non-`nil` values.

For instance, this sorts `nil` values before both `false` and `true`:

```
stores.sort { Int($0.flagship ?? -1) < Int($1.flagship ?? -1) }
```

This sorts `nil` values after both `false` and `true`:

```
stores.sort { Int($0.flagship ?? 2) < Int($1.flagship ?? 2) }
```

You can use the same pattern to make `nil` compare the same as `true` or the same as `false`. It's up to you.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another approach.

You can use `flatMap` which will remove `nil` objects and unwrap those that are present. Then, the force unwrap will be safe to sort:

```
let flagshipStores = stores.flatMap({ return $0.flagship ? $0 : nil }).sort {
    $0.flagship! && !$1.flagship!
}
```

This will remove stores with a `nil` flagship from the array.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$0.flagship == true && $1.flagship != true
```

The left side will succeed if the value is not nil and is true, the right side will succeed if the value is either nil or false.

Answer (score 2):

As mr.Fixit pointed out on a comment, the accepted answer doesn't fully work because it doesn't take care of nils. Here is the correct answer with an extra string sample.

SWIFT 4

for a boolean sorting

```
 let flagshipStores = self.stores.sorted(by: {
    guard let flagship0 = $0.flagship, let flagship1 = $1.flagship else { 

       if $0.flagship == nil && $1.flagship == nil || $0.flagship != nil &&  $1.flagship == nil{

          return true

       }
       else {

          return false

       }
    } 

    return ($0.flagship == $1.flagship || $0.flagship == true && $1.flagship == false ? true : false)


 })
```

for strings comparison sorting

```
 let stores = self.stores.sorted(by: {
    guard let store0 = $0.store, let store1 = $1.store else { 

       if $0.store == nil && $1.store == nil || $0.store != nil &&  $1.store == nil{

          return true

       }
       else {

          return false

       }
    } 

    return ( ($0.store)?.localizedStandardCompare($1.store!) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending )

 })
```

Answer (score 2):

To filter `nil` values just use `compactMap` before `sort`

```
let flagshipStores = self.stores.compactMap { return $0.flagship }.sorted {
    $0 && !$1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this function to compare the Optional values without the need to unwrap.

```
func sortOptionalValues<T: Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool? {
    switch (lhs != nil, rhs != nil) {
    case (false, false):
        return nil
    case (true, false):
        return true
    case (false, true):
        return false
    case (true, true):
        guard let lhs = lhs, let rhs = rhs else { return nil }
        return lhs < rhs
    }
}
```