# sort an array with Custom Objects swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

```
public class OfferObjectModel: JSONJoy {
    let rank : Int?
    }

offersList.sort(by: { $0.rank < $1.rank }) -->Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'Int?' operands
offersList is an array of OfferObjectModel
```

Comment: Handle the optionals.

Comment: Didnt work after handling the optionals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swift - sort an array of objects by their optional boolean property without force unwrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39059248/swift-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-their-optional-boolean-property-without-forc)

Comment: "Didnt work after handling the optionals. " And what did you write in that case to handle them? Could it be because you didn't handle them correctly?

Comment: Handle the optionals. - this worked. I was doing in a wrong way. Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
a.sort { (first, second) -> Bool in
guard let firstRank = first.rank else { return true }
guard let secondRank = second.rank else { return false }
return firstRank < secondRank
}
```

So this code block will make sure your nil ranks will be first and then sorted by rank value. And if change this part:

```
guard let firstRank = first.rank else { return false }
guard let secondRank = second.rank else { return true }
```

Nil ranks will be at the end. 
And please make sure that your array is mutable.