# Swift array sorted by optional properties

Tags: arrays, swift

I use this code to sort array:

```
self.sortedArray = unsortedArray.sorted{($0 as PersonEntity).name!.caseInsensitiveCompare(($1 as PersonEntity).name!) == .orderedAscending}
```

What I don't like is this code is force unwrapping, how to iterate through optional to sort them in this case?

I found a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39059248/swift-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-their-optional-boolean-property-without-forc) with sorting bool optional but when I try to sort string optionals properties with guarded values it crashes with log unexpected found nil.

Comment: Use `??` to map a nil name to some value that will make it sort as desired.

Comment: Unrelated but there should be no need for the `as PersonEntity` cast.

Comment: just use `.compactMap` at first in your chain.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422533/sort-nil-to-the-end-of-an-array-of-optional-strings

Comment: Is it really necessary that the property is optional? In practice every person is supposed to have a name.

Comment: Try this, `unsortedArray.sorted { $0.name?.caseInsensitiveCompare($1.name ?? "") == .orderedAscending }`

Comment: @Kamran yea looks like it works, thanks!